# Check calculated ranking for Sphinx results?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Is there any way to calculate ranking/relevance of documents returned while querying using ThinkingSphinx? I have weighted fields and I know that one can use `:match_mode=>:extended` and `:order=>"@relevance desc"` but is there any way the calculated weights for each documents can be shown?

I have used Solr and it gives this support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not used thinkingsphinx, but did find this in the FAQ :)

http://pat.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#weights